# Immediate email push notifications account + app combos?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, gmail, apns

Which accounts (e.g. @gmail.com, @outlook.com, @icloud.com, etc.) paired with which apps (e.g. Mail, Gmail, Outlook, etc.) will give me immediate push notifications for any email received?

I'm looking for those combinations that generate a push notification within 5 seconds.

For example, imagine if when Outlook is paired with a Gmail account, it uses 15 minute polling to determine when a new message arrives. This would not satisfy my requirement above. On the other hand, imagine you use the built-in mail app with an @icloud.com account, and you enable Push in the settings. This should send immediate push notifications, satisfying the requirement above.

I'm looking for several solutions, not just one so that I can have multiple "inboxes" or workflows.

Comment: All email clients for iOS support push notifications and will give you instant notification for received email. The whole point of having push notification technology in the first place is to rid the client from having to poll the server at regular interval.

Comment: Gmail app has instant push for gmail accounts. It also supports multiple inboxes and now even offers an “all inboxes” view. I recently switched from mail to gmail for those 2 reasons (I mainly only use gmail addresses).